# How optimal is this function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm about to implement this function to calculate some numbers.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funLookupFTE] (@PFID int) RETURNS
    VARCHAR(20) AS BEGIN 

DECLARE @NumberOfFTE AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @NumberOfFTE = (SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Hours <= 20 THEN 0.5 WHEN Hours > 20 THEN 1     END) AS FTECount 
                    FROM tblPractitioners 
                    WHERE PFID =
@PFID)
RETURN @NumberOfFTE
END
```

Just trying to see if it's optimal and it won't take matters into its own hand.

Comment: why are you returning a SUM value as a varchar(20)?

Comment: Is not the function that matters, is your schema. What indexes you have, what cardinality do the tables have?

Answer (score 4):

If this is to be called in any sort of query, you're probably better off using a subquery instead of a user-defined function.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tblPractioners P1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  PFID, SUM(CASE WHEN Hours <= 20 THEN 0.5 WHEN Hours > 20 THEN 1 END) 
        AS FTECount 
    FROM tblPractitioners 
    GROUP BY PFID
) P2 ON P1.PFID = P2.PFID
```

Performance of user-defined functions can be very poor, but you'll really need to compare the execution plans using a subquery or UDF to see which is better.

Comment: @OMG - Hey, I was gone to dinner for a few hours, you guys had your chance.  And whoops, didn't realize how late it was!

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Look who's talking!! :-) :-) Both of you leave some for the rest of us, i say!! :-)

Comment: @InSane: Sir, you *wound* me! :)

Comment: I'm cracked up by your comments :) but thanks for the insights.